# How can I commit a file in CVS without checking out the repository

Tags: cvs

In CVS, I can perform some operations remotely, without having a checked-out repository:

```
cvs -d <repo> rlog <file>
cvs -d <repo> rls <dir>
```

I can even checkout out a single file:

```
cvs -d <repo> checkout -p <file>
```

Is there a way to commit a file without checking out the repository in CVS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

This is because cvs requires some of the metadata stored in the `CVS` folder in order to do some operations, including commits. The most important entries in this instance are `Root` and `Repository`.

`Root` gives the location of the cvs repository (though technically you can provide that on the command line). `Repository` tells you the path of the file within the repository. This second one cannot be passed on the command line so you have no way of telling cvs what file in the repository to actually apply any changes to.

[Section 2.3 of the CVS manual](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.11.23/cvs_2.html#SEC19) explains more about the files in the `CVS` folder.

Comment: I use that `cvs checkout -p` code a lot; it works, at least with the CVS client I use: 1.12.13. The `-p` makes CVS write the file to stdout instead of writing it to the current directory.

Comment: Ah, intriguing. I thought you had meant to type "-P" (prune directories) which confused me a little. I wasn't aware that the "-p" option even existed. Thanks for that! What I said about the metadata needed stands though, and the single file checkout without "-p" will still give you the bare necessary files to commit your changes.